# how I can centralize problem details in .net 7

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

When I do `return NotFound` it includes problem details, but when I do `return NotFound(message)` it just returns message. I wanna have consistency whenever I add message or not.

Is there any way to centralize it for error responses?

Comment: [Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#pds7) the options range from replacing the ExceptionHandling middleware to replacing the ProblemDetails middleware to configuring the existing one. Choose whats best fits to your application.

Comment: [Global-error-handling tutorial](https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/).

Comment: the thing is I am not using exception based error handling. My services returns Results and based on them I can return 404, 400 and etc. @Ralf

Comment: As you presumably found out you can just return anything with those methods and you can do something like `return NotFound(new ProblemDetails(.....));` but be assured that will get messy. Read the docs and try to find a more structured solution using a fitting middleware.

Comment: @Ralf I knew it mate. I thought there is some structured solution to not get messy with creation each time. Middleware approach seems good but how to identify that 40X erros is returned? I mean when there is an exception you can do whatever you want in middleware/filters. But in my case I need something to override default behavior

Comment: Middlewares get a HttpContext that will contains almost any context info and the statuscode is one of that.

Comment: What you mean all errors?  Controller return error like status codes(400+)or all the server exception(500+)?